# Raised a flag on a code-only answer which is mostly a copy-paste and the flag got declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I raised a flag for this [particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58280572/3981539) 
because the script contains

document.getElementById( **'list-home-list'** );

and

document.getElementsByTagName(**'hb'**);

which are not at all related to the code which the OP had added along with the question. Since the person is new to Stackoverflow, I thought of adding a reason "Needs to be edited to explain what it is all about". I didn't feel that the code shared is related to the question asked.

Although document.getElementById is purely Javascript and used internally by JQuery, I think the answer is just a copy paste.

The flag got declined saying "Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". Is it advisable to let copy paste random code to remain there with this question? What could be a better way of addressing the issue if the flag I raised was wrong?

Comment: "Code Only" is not a reason to flag an answer.  It's a reason (if you think the code isn't self-explanatory enough) to downvote an answer (as 'unclear').  I can't see any code on any other answers that match this answer; so it wouldn't be advisable to flag it as 'copy/paste', as that has specific meaning to us (meaning they plagiarized another answer). Plagiarism has a specific meaning as well -- not that the code covers the same ground, but that it is 100% word-for-word a copy of another answer. In this case, no flags are necessary; the community can downvote if not useful.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - thank you for explaining that. After reading your comment, I feel unclear should have been a better flag. I will keep your advice in mind reviewing questions from now on.

Comment: It may be a *bad* answer but it's not "not an answer". Something that is "not an answer" will be, say, `"I like ice cream"`, (completely unrelated) or `"can you share code?"` (should be a comment), `"I have this problem, too!"` (irrelevant to the question), `"I tried X but got an problem with Y"` (new question), etc. Those are **not** answers. If somebody tries to solve OP's problem, even incorrectly, that's still an answer.

Comment: Keep in mind “unclear” isn’t a reason to “flag” (flag means to hit the “flag” link and ask a moderator to step in). Unclear is a reason to downvote (meaning hit the down arrow to the left of the answer under its number score).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - so if i find the answer to be unclear would it be advisable to flag it along with downvoting so that the moderator who reviews the answer and related flags or downvotes can understand why i downvoted?

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran you don't need to flag to explain your downvotes. Nobody is going to check if they are "legitimate". Well, outside checking for serial downvoting (which is normally automatic). But if you just find an answer and don't like it for any reason (unclear, incorrect, using anti-patterns, or even the variable names are funny), then you can downvote it. You don't need to give an explanation to anybody. Flagging should be done for *serious* content problems - plagiarism, illegal activities, spam, etc. As a rule of thumb, if you feel it should be deleted.

Comment: @VLAZ - That was something new which I learnt today :) I will stick to this rule of thumb from now on.

Comment: Think of it this way: Flagging - something is so out of place with this post that a person needs to stop what they're doing and step in and delete it. Voting - This post is wrong, or not helpful, or not clear.  Also think of it from the person who's being flagged point of view: Would you want your post deleted in 'normal' circumstances?